# Can't call generic function from a generic struct

Tags: swift, generics

I have a problem when trying to create a function in extension which would call another generic function.
I created very simple example to display the problem :

```
protocol Target {}
enum api {
    case user
}
extension api: Target {}
protocol Mappable {}

struct User {}
extension User: Mappable {}

struct Provider<A: Target> {

}
extension Provider {

    func requestObject<T: Mappable>(_ token: A, type: T.Type){
        //some code
    }

    func getUser() {

        requestObject(api.user, type: User.self)
        //This code creates Error:  Cannot invoke 'requestObject' with an argument list of type '(api, type: User.Type)'
    }

}
```

Can anyone help and explain how can create a function getUser() and call requestObject. I know that one solution would be to make struct Provider non-generic, but than It will limit Provider, therefore its not really a solution.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that by extending the generic `Provider` type without any type constraints and declaring the `getUser` function as you did, the compiler can only infer the type of `A` to be `Api`, which is more restrictive than `A:Target`. You need to use conditional conformance to let the compiler know that the specific `getUser` implementation should only exist for `Provider` types specialised with the `api` type.

```
extension Provider where A == Api {
    func getUser() {
        requestObject(Api.user, type: User.self)
    }
}
```

You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is upperCamelCase for types, so change `api` to `Api`.

Comment: Hi Dávid Pásztor,  Thanks for the answer, it works ! :)

Comment: @VanillaThunder glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

```
protocol Target {

}
enum api {
    case user
}
extension api: Target {}
protocol Mappable {}

struct User {}
extension User: Mappable {}

struct Provider<A: Target> {

}
extension Provider {

   func requestObject<T : Mappable>(_ token: A, type: T.Type) {
      //some code
   }

   static func getUser() {
       let provider = Provider<api>()
       provider.requestObject(api.user, type: User.self)
       //This code creates Error:  Cannot invoke 'requestObject' with an argument list of type '(api, type: User.Type)'
   }

}
```

As far as I understand your `Provider` struct is generic itself, so to call it you must specialise it first. Otherwise the compiler cannot infer the type of T in your requestObject call.

Comment: This is what conditional conformance is for. Creating a new, specialised provider inside the `getUser` function is a bad idea, you should simply be able to call it from the instance of `Provider` you're working with and shouldn't have to make the function static either.

Comment: I know, I just didn't get what the author tried to do at a glance. I'd argue that writing those extensions will be confusing for more advanced cases though - and i'd personally specialise providers (or extend targets) to make them more readable. I like what Moya lib did.